# How to iterate over a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, loops, multidimensional-array, foreach, iteration

I have array like this. This array is created dynamically

```
 Array
 (
  [Data NotUploading] => Array
    (
        [items] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [date] => 2013-04-02
                        [issue_id] => 1
                        [phone_service_device] => A
                        [phone_service_model] => 
                        [phone_service_os] => 
                        [phone_service_version] => 
                        [issue_name] => Data NotUploading
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [date] => 2013-04-02
                        [issue_id] => 1
                        [phone_service_device] => I
                        [phone_service_model] => 
                        [phone_service_os] => 
                        [phone_service_version] => 
                        [issue_name] => Data NotUploading
                    )



            )

    )

[Battery Problem] => Array
    (
        [items] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [date] => 2013-04-03
                        [issue_id] => 3
                        [phone_service_device] => I
                        [phone_service_model] => 
                        [phone_service_os] => 
                        [phone_service_version] => 
                        [issue_name] => Battery Problem
                    )

            )

    )
)
```

What I need to do is to use 2 `foreach` or 1 foreach & 1 for loop so that I can get each value of date I did like this

```
 foreach($gResultbyName  as $key1 => $rec){
         for($j = 0;$j<count($rec);$j++ ){
             echo $rec['items'][$j]['date']; 
         }
     }
```

but its only retrieving 2013-04-02 & 2013-04-03 that is 0 index date of data NotUploading & 0 index date of Battery Problem. Basically I need to compare each value and others stuff but I just cant get each date value.

Forgive me for ignorance but I tried a lot :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
foreach ($data as $d)
{
    foreach($d['items'] as $item)
    {
        echo $item['date'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your for-loop loops `count($rec)` times, but should `count($rec['items'])`.

Answer (score 2):

This should load the dates into an array sorted by the issue_name. The you can step through them for further processing.

```
$dates= array();
foreach ($gResultbyName AS $events){
    foreach ($events['items'] AS $item){
        $dates[$item['issue_name']][] = $item['date'];
    }
}
var_dump($dates);
```